# Microsoft Access Subform Text Box (grows) with Vertical Bars - Upon Open show BOTTOM of the Text Box

Tags: vba, ms-access, properties, subform

I have created a tabbed set of sub-forms in Microsoft Access. Each sub-form has different controls and data type objects. On one sub-form, when I go to that tab I want a text box to show the content of the BOTTOM of the text box, so I do not have the scroll down to the bottom each time. I cannot find an associated property. So I either need the correct property name or it's in the VB code for Form_Load, but I do not know how to write it. Please let me know. Thank you.

I've Googled and reviewed all of the properties.

Comment: Explore SelStart property http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0011.htm and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/enabled-enterfieldbehavior-sellength-selstart-seltext-properties-example